# Make the images same size in grid card

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

I made some card using grid and flexbox for the content. The image is not the same size each cards. I use the display grid for the wrapper and flexbox for the card content. I tried to use flex-grow and flex-basis in the trackcard_header class, but nothing works. I attach the sample of my code result below, please take a look to the snippet too.

Here is the screenshot:
[image: Result]

And this is my snippet:

```css
.createpl_card_wrapper {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 2rem;
  grid-row-gap: 1rem;
}
.trackcard {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
  position: relative;
}
.trackcard_header {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
.trackcard_header img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
.trackcard_body {
  padding: 1rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
.trackcard_body h2 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.trackcard_body h4 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
.trackcard_footer {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
.trackcard_btn {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.25rem 0;
  background-color: #1db954;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid #1db954;
  color: #fff;
}
.trackcard_btn:hover {
  background-color: #18a349;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/styles.css" />

  <body>
    <div class="createpl_card_wrapper">
      <div class="trackcard">
        <div class="trackcard_header">
          <img
            src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b2738c0defcb336a0296eb7d704a"
            alt="name"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="trackcard_body">
          <h2>GANADARA (Feat. IU)</h2>
          <h4>
            Jay Park - GANADARA
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="trackcard_footer">
          <button type="button" class="trackcard_btn">
            Select
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="trackcard">
        <div class="trackcard_header">
          <img
            src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273c63be04ae902b1da7a54d247"
            alt="name"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="trackcard_body">
          <h2>eight(Prod.&Feat. SUGA of BTS)</h2>
          <h4>
            IU - eight
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="trackcard_footer">
          <button type="button" class="trackcard_btn">
            Select
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="trackcard">
        <div class="trackcard_header">
          <img
            src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27315cf3110f19687b1a24943d1"
            alt="name"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="trackcard_body">
          <h2>Good day</h2>
          <h4>
            IU - REAL
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="trackcard_footer">
          <button type="button" class="trackcard_btn">
            Select
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="trackcard">
        <div class="trackcard_header">
          <img
            src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b2734ed058b71650a6ca2c04adff"
            alt="name"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="trackcard_body">
          <h2>Celebrity</h2>
          <h4>
            IU - IU 5th Album 'LILAC'
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="trackcard_footer">
          <button type="button" class="trackcard_btn">
            Select
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="trackcard">
        <div class="trackcard_header">
          <img
            src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273a1d785640d9421ec17ea8fe6"
            alt="name"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="trackcard_body">
          <h2>BBIBBI</h2>
          <h4>
            IU - BBIBBI
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="trackcard_footer">
          <button type="button" class="trackcard_btn">
            Select
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to make the images is in the same size, both vertically and horizontally. Could anyone give me solution? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be achieved with some JavaScript.

First you select all the elements with `querySelectorAll`. You then make an array of its height with `offsetHeight`. `Math.max` returns the largest sum of the input parameter.

In a for loop, you can set the elements `minHeight` with `Math.max`. It keeps looping until it finds the length and then applies the styling. Keep in mind this will apply the height of the largest image as `min-height` on all of your images.

And while we're at it, I did the same thing for the `h2`-elements, so they're aligned equally in all the cards. I separated the JS so it is easier to read and understand. The only gotcha is you have to reload the page if you drag the screen size, as the min-height will be a bit off.

**As for CSS** I used `grid-template-columns: repeat(5, minmax(200px, 1fr));` instead. This way there will always be 5 columns that are atleast 200px wide, so they have an equal size. If you want a responsive effect, just edit the `5` out with `auto-fit`, this way they will wrap on smaller screens.

Like so:

`grid-template-columns: repeat(5, minmax(auto-fit, 1fr));`

If you want to change the `width` or `height` of your images, I suggest using `max-width` and `max-height` for a responsive effect. If you don't change the width, they will look a bit stretched.

You can apply `object-fit: cover;` on the images also, this way the image won't be stretched, but a bit of the image will be cut off instead.

I hope this helps you!
**Snippet below will not work properly, check Codepen: https://codepen.io/sigurdmazanti/pen/qBpLGXe**

```js
let img = document.querySelectorAll(".trackcard_header img");
let text = document.querySelectorAll(".trackcard_body h2");

// Image
let imgLength = Array.from(img).map(e => e.offsetHeight);
let maxLength = Math.max(...imgLength);


// H2
let textLength = Array.from(text).map(e => e.offsetHeight);
let maxTextLength = Math.max(...textLength);

// Image for loop
for (let i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
  img[i].style.minHeight = maxLength + "px";
}

// H2 for loop
for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  text[i].style.minHeight = maxTextLength + "px";
}
```

```css
.createpl_card_wrapper {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  display: grid;
  /*grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr); */
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-column-gap: 2rem;
  grid-row-gap: 1rem;
}

.trackcard {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 100%;
  padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
  position: relative;
}

.trackcard_header {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.trackcard_header img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  /* Consider this */
  object-fit: cover;
}

.trackcard_body {
  padding: 1rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}

.trackcard_body h2 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.trackcard_body h4 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.trackcard_footer {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}

.trackcard_btn {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.25rem 0;
  background-color: #1db954;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid #1db954;
  color: #fff;
}

.trackcard_btn:hover {
  background-color: #18a349;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/styles.css" />

<body>
  <div class="createpl_card_wrapper">
    <div class="trackcard">
      <div class="trackcard_header">
        <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b2738c0defcb336a0296eb7d704a" alt="name" />
      </div>
      <div class="trackcard_body">
        <h2>GANADARA (Feat. IU)</h2>
        <h4>
          Jay Park - GANADARA
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="trackcard_footer">
        <button type="button" class="trackcard_btn">
            Select
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="trackcard">
      <div class="trackcard_header">
        <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273c63be04ae902b1da7a54d247" alt="name" />
      </div>
      <div class="trackcard_body">
        <h2>eight(Prod.&Feat. SUGA of BTS)</h2>
        <h4>
          IU - eight
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="trackcard_footer">
        <button type="button" class="trackcard_btn">
            Select
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="trackcard">
      <div class="trackcard_header">
        <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27315cf3110f19687b1a24943d1" alt="name" />
      </div>
      <div class="trackcard_body">
        <h2>Good day</h2>
        <h4>
          IU - REAL
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="trackcard_footer">
        <button type="button" class="trackcard_btn">
            Select
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="trackcard">
      <div class="trackcard_header">
        <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b2734ed058b71650a6ca2c04adff" alt="name" />
      </div>
      <div class="trackcard_body">
        <h2>Celebrity</h2>
        <h4>
          IU - IU 5th Album 'LILAC'
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="trackcard_footer">
        <button type="button" class="trackcard_btn">
            Select
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="trackcard">
      <div class="trackcard_header">
        <img src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273a1d785640d9421ec17ea8fe6" alt="name" />
      </div>
      <div class="trackcard_body">
        <h2>BBIBBI</h2>
        <h4>
          IU - BBIBBI
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="trackcard_footer">
        <button type="button" class="trackcard_btn">
            Select
          </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="src/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the divs an actual size, in your code, they only have % values and no parent static value to take the %age out of. I've given the `.trackcard` class a width of `30vw`. In order to make the images square, you also need to give it a height that's not dependent on other height values, but have the same value as the width, so I gave it a placeholder of `24vw` which is 80% of the `.trackcard`. You need to use [`object-fit: contain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) to not stretch. You can refer to the docs I linked and use the one you prefer.

```css
.createpl_card_wrapper {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-column-gap: 2rem;
  grid-row-gap: 1rem;
}
.trackcard {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 1rem;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 30vw;
  padding: 1rem 0.5rem;
  position: relative;
}
.trackcard_header {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
.trackcard_header img {
  width: 24vw;
  height: 24vw;
  object-fit: contain;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}
.trackcard_body {
  padding: 1rem;
  flex-grow: 1;
  text-align: center;
}
.trackcard_body h2 {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}
.trackcard_body h4 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
.trackcard_footer {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
.trackcard_btn {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0.25rem 0;
  background-color: #1db954;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border: 1px solid #1db954;
  color: #fff;
}
.trackcard_btn:hover {
  background-color: #18a349;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./src/styles.css" />

  <body>
    <div class="createpl_card_wrapper">
      <div class="trackcard">
        <div class="trackcard_header">
          <img
            src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b2738c0defcb336a0296eb7d704a"
            alt="name"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="trackcard_body">
          <h2>GANADARA (Feat. IU)</h2>
          <h4>
            Jay Park - GANADARA
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="trackcard_footer">
          <button type="button" class="trackcard_btn">
            Select
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="trackcard">
        <div class="trackcard_header">
          <img
            src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273c63be04ae902b1da7a54d247"
            alt="name"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="trackcard_body">
          <h2>eight(Prod.&Feat. SUGA of BTS)</h2>
          <h4>
            IU - eight
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="trackcard_footer">
          <button type="button" class="trackcard_btn">
            Select
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="trackcard">
        <div class="trackcard_header">
          <img
            src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27315cf3110f19687b1a24943d1"
            alt="name"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="trackcard_body">
          <h2>Good day</h2>
          <h4>
            IU - REAL
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="trackcard_footer">
          <button type="button" class="trackcard_btn">
            Select
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="trackcard">
        <div class="trackcard_header">
          <img
            src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b2734ed058b71650a6ca2c04adff"
            alt="name"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="trackcard_body">
          <h2>Celebrity</h2>
          <h4>
            IU - IU 5th Album 'LILAC'
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="trackcard_footer">
          <button type="button" class="trackcard_btn">
            Select
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="trackcard">
        <div class="trackcard_header">
          <img
            src="https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b273a1d785640d9421ec17ea8fe6"
            alt="name"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="trackcard_body">
          <h2>BBIBBI</h2>
          <h4>
            IU - BBIBBI
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="trackcard_footer">
          <button type="button" class="trackcard_btn">
            Select
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, even it's not really responsive :)